# In Java servlets, why are attributes defined only for context, request and session scopes?

Tags: java, servlets, attributes

In servlets, `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` are only associated with `HttpSession`, `ServletRequest` and `ServletContext`, i.e attributes are defined only for context, request and session scopes. Why not for, say, `ServletResponse` or `ServletConfig`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ServletConfig is for `init-params` defined in web.xml.
- Setting attribute to `HttpServletResponse` will not avail anything, and neither it will make any sense, as response is for the client -- not from the client, i.e. browser, and that is not capable of understanding that, nonetheless. And you must understand that JSP and Servlet both run on server-side, whatsoever. Hence, settng attributes to `request` in servlet and getting those in JSP, doesn't involve the client at all.

Answer (score 6):

Attributes always apply to some scope. For example, if you want them to apply to the current request only, then you bind them to the request object.

Similarly, if you want it to apply to the current session, then you bind them to the session object. Attributes relevant to the entire running application instance are set on the servlet context object.

The objects you proposed have the exact same scope, as those already provided: The response has the same scope (a.k.a lifetime) as the request. The servlet config has the exact same scope as the servlet context.

Therefore, adding `getAttribute()`/`setAttribute()` on those methods would only add to the confusion ("did I set the attribute on the request or on the response?") and not add any additional features.

Answer (score 0):

the "request" scope is really the "request-response" scope.